# What does r-bounded waiting mean in the context of Peterson's algorithm and the filter algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

Recently, I have been taught Peterson's algorithm. While searching online I found that the algorithm could be extended to n-processes, the filter algorithm. However, many sources I come across mention that the filter algorithm does not have r-bounded waiting when Peterson's algorithm does. This was not a term I had been taught (I had only learnt of mutual exclusion, progress and no starvation, and I have found that both algorithms satisfy all three properties), and the definition I found on Wikipedia is as follows:

```
Bounded waiting, or bounded bypass, means that the number of times a process is bypassed by another process after it has indicated its desire to enter the critical section is bounded by a function of the number of processes in the system.
```

However, I am still unable to understand what this means. What does it mean to "indicate its desire to enter the critical section"? If I were to interpret it as calling the function that locks the critical section, then for Peterson's algorithm, can I not have Process 2 enter the critical section many times while Process 1 is setting the two variables before the wait? In this sense, will not Peterson's algorithm also not have r-bounded waiting?

I hope someone will be able to use these algorithms as an example to help me understand this concept of r-bounded waiting.